# Attaching fields to files

Tags: 7, media, files

I have a couple of forms where I need to attach metadata fields to files (a description, and a category).

The file_entity module alone lets me specify fields, but doesn't change the form fields.

When enabling the Media module, it sort of works, but the Media module

1. does its work in an overlay, which is unacceptable - I need something that looks like if you enable the "description" option in the core File element
2. breaks the look of the site as soon as I click on the "edit" button that opens the overlay - it loads the entire Bartik CSS even if the current theme is not related or using Bartik!
3. is way too overcrowded - I don't need support for youtube
4. is a security hole because people can browse all uploaded files!

So, basically, I need some way to attach a dropdown box to the standard file upload widget, nothing more - how do I achieve this? If possible, I'd prefer something that integrates at least with file_entity, so I don't have to define the field in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something like https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_inline